# Linguex with TeXLive 2016 - "ended by" errors

Tags: linguex, texlive-2016

Has anyone had issues with Linguex glossed examples after updating to TeXLive 2016?

Here’s a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}    
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}    

\exg.  Dies ist nicht die erste Glosse\\
         This is not the first gloss\\

\end{document}
```

I get the following errors:

```
E: foo.tex:10 \begin{list} on input line 10 ended by \end{flushleft}.
E: foo.tex:10 Missing } inserted
E: foo.tex:10 \begin{document} ended by \end{list}.
E: foo.tex:16 Extra \endgroup
```

If I switch back to TeXLive 2015, it works flawlessly...  Glossed examples using gb4e or just plain cgloss4e.sty work fine, too.
Any thoughts?

Comment: I get no errors with texlive 2016 updated today add `\listfiles` to your preamble and then post the list from the log in a code block in your question.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was caused by a broken installation.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a bum copy of cgloss4e.sty.  Replacing that in my texmf folder with a new copy fixed everything.